# VB.Net  - how to support implicit type conversion as well as custom equality

Tags: vb.net, clr, type-conversion

**Fixed:  See notes at bottom**

I am implementing a generic class that supports two features, implicit type conversion and custom equality operators.  Well, it supports IN-equality as well, if it does that.

```
1) if ( "value" = myInstance ) then ...
2) Dim s As String = myInstance
3) Dim s As String = CType(myInstance,String)
```

The problem I am having is that if I support #2, implicit conversion, then I can't get my equality operators to work, since they complain about no conversion being the most specific.

The error I get is this (simplified a bit for brevity):

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible '=' is most specific for these arguments:
    'Public Shared Operator =(obj As MyClass, data As String) As Boolean': Not most specific.
    'Public Shared Operator =(data As String, obj As MyClass) As Boolean': Not most specific.
    'Public Shared Operator =(obj1 As MyClass, obj2 As MyClass) As Boolean': Not most specific.
```

What is the best way of implementing this.  Just as importantly, what should I leave out?   I have implemented the following conversions

```
Operator =(ByVal data As String,    ByVal obj  As classType) As Boolean (and <>)
Operator =(ByVal obj  As classType, byval data As String) As Boolean (and <>)
Operator =(ByVal obj1 As classType, ByVal obj2 As classType) As Boolean (and <>)
Equals(obj as Object) as Boolean
Equals(compareTo as classType ) as Boolean
Equals(compareTo as String) as Boolean
Widening Operator CType(ByVal source As String) As classType
Widening Operator CType(ByVal source As classType) as String
Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal inst As classType) As dataType
```

In my widening operator I do some reflection, which is why I wanted to be able to do an implicit convert DOWN to String when I do a comparison or assignment with the string on the left side.

```
A) SomeObject.StringPropertySetter = MyClass
```

### **Fix** (edit)

I went way overboard in what I implemented, because I didn't understand what was happening.  Comparison between the base types (ie string/double/guid) takes place via the widening ctype(...) as String (or Guid,etc) operator.  In the end, i just implemented these functions and all my test cases still pass, in addition to assignment from the class to a base type instance

```
Public Class MyClass(Of BaseType)

    Widening Operator CType(ByVal source As dataType) As MyClass 
    Widening Operator CType(ByVal source As MyClass) As dataType //conv between inst & base
    Equals()  // for datatype, classType, object
    Operator <>(MyClass,MyClass) // for comparison between two instances
    Opeator   =(MyClass,MyClass)
```

*comments are c style, but code is vb.net*

Of course the class is a little more complicated than that, but that give me everything I needed :)

Comment: Wow, two years sitting here and it didn't cause an issue.  Are you sure you want to start doing this type of edit, considering nearly every *single* issue I see on the sidebar says "vb.net", "linq", etc.  This dones't really make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not override the = operator. If you have implicit conversions to types such as `string` or `int`, then let the default equality operator take over.

As a general rule, if you need to customize equality for a class you should override the `Equals(object)` method.